# Google Map Custom Buttons

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I'm creating A button just like the default button in Google Map.
But I cant figure how they did it.
Tried searching but no luck.
I want it to look like this(Pls see pic below).
I want my button to be look like the one with googlemap default.
A button with A icon.
[image]

So far this is only my code.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context="com.toweeloapp.fragments.Nearby">


<com.toweeloapp.custom.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/noContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="There's no shops nearby."
    android:textColor="@color/textSecondary"
    android:textSize="@dimen/title"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<com.toweeloapp.custom.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/errorContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Can't load places right now"
    android:textColor="@color/textSecondary"
    android:textSize="@dimen/title"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/rvRefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/mapHolder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="350dp"
                >

                <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                    android:id="@+id/mapImageView"
                    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    map:cameraZoom="15"
                    map:liteMode="false"
                    map:mapType="normal"/>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="bottom|right">

                    <Button
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:id="@+id/btnResize"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvNearby"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: show us your layout file

Comment: Done sir.  I just want to my button to looked like google's. But can't figure out how.

Comment: did u created the below button?

Comment: yup. It supposed to be a button for resizing the map. Its just a simple implementation of a button. But I want it to looked like google's

Comment: what do u mean by resizing?

Comment: I have a functionality that can resize the Map. Make it smaller or full screen. It's not zoom functionality. My problem is I want to make my button just looked like google's

Comment: Wouldn't using an `ImageButton` and creating the image similar to google suffice for this? Lets say having an image with 50% opacity and setting it instead of a regular `Button`?